# I found a virus on my USB stick. Now what?

Tags: virus

I discovered a file, named **autorun.ini** on my USB flash drive:

> [AutoRun]
> ;FjYfoT
> ;jpId  UagEbddsb PCjo
> oPEn = efhcnu.exe
> sheLl\open\DEfault=1
> ;utvDpsMqpT dDustbemW XyAy WeywFbvaVA eQnK
> sHeLL\open\COmmanD = efhcnu.exe
> ;uRprWb
> ShEll\expLore\coMmANd = efhcnu.exe
> ;kdtrelceNy uEeF gFTf
> shEll\autoPLAy\commAND = efhcnu.exe

Both it and the accompanying efhcnu.exe are hidden under windows and are visible only after *"Show system files"* is enabled.

efhcnu.exe has size 168kB.

My priorities are:

- identify which computers were infected and what is the damage
- remove the malware
- report this incident to the public

[image]

**How should I proceed?**

Comment: Could you please mail the `exe` to `epsvpeqb@sharklasers.com` I have some spare time today and could analyze it for you.

Comment: you are awesome lynks

Comment: @lynks, you are getting it. Maybe I should post a hexdump somewhere online for everyone to see?

Comment: @lynks, unfortunately, my antivirus programs, gmail detects the virus and won't allow me to send it. Tonight I will attempt to send you the hexdump.

Comment: @Vorac that email address expires in 40 minutes or so, try renaming the file to a `.jpg`

Comment: @lynks, it is done!

Comment: @Vorac received, thanks. I will post any findings either tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: One AV IDed it. W32.Sality.AE; http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2008-042106-1847-99

Comment: @lynks, do you have any insights? The symantec page listed some symptoms, which my computers do not have. However, the virus lives on, morphing the executable file's name and affecting other executables.

Comment: @Vorac yeah I had a look, the *only* symptom that I was able to confirm from the W32.Sality definition was that it generates a random name for itself. It also changes a lot of registry keys relating to notepad, which is not mentioned anywhere regarding W32.Sality. Beyond that I was struggling; it's obfuscated and quite large. I will post my exact findings as an answer later, I'm away from them right now.

Comment: @lynks any news?

Answer (score 12):

Step 1 - Nuke your USB drive. Format the thing.

Step 2 - Nuke all the computers that you have used the USB drive with in the period which you suspect the drive has been infected.

Step 3 - Change your passwords.

Step 4 - Submit the malware to something like [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/). It will ensure that most of the major antivirus vendors pick up on it.

Step 5 - Harden all Windows computers you work with by following guidelines posted by [NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsSPs.html), including disabling all autorun features for all types of media.

Comment: But how do I know if any of my online accounts are compromised? What about the backups?

Comment: @Vorac Change all your passwords. Treat backups as you would a computer. If it has been in contact with the USB drive in the suspected period, it has to go.

Comment: Can you specify which of those publications you're referring to?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a Linux OS (for example Ubuntu) to backup your files from USB and scan them with an antivirus, so you can save your files; then you will must format your USB stick!

Comment: Or alternatively, just make a permanent switch to a Linux OS (for example Ubuntu) rendering the virus on the USB stick (and any other Windows malware you come across) impotent. ;)